# NFS share with user login

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba, nfs

I have a samba share, which works fine on my windows machine. I've setup a user with a password, that has to be given to the server on mount. It's secure and easy.

But now I have an Ubuntu machine and the samba share doesn't work that great. Appareantly it only wants to work on the servers local network, where it can see the WORKGROUP the samba share has set.

So I decided to setup an NFS share, but it turns out, that can be mounted by anyone who has my servers IP and as I use the server for other, not so secure and very public, things that's not good.

Setting a static IP or specific user IDs are out of the question, as they can be easilly faked. So it would be great, if I could setup a system, that recuires the same username and password given to the server on mount, as the samba share uses.

How to?

Comment: NFS V4 allows authentication using `kerberos` (see e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto or https://we.riseup.net/stefani/kerberos-and-nfs4)